# D3 Graph Layout - Tree Structure With multiple Parent

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, layout

Let me start off with stating that I am completely new to D3 and Javascript. And with little bit of experimenting it I was trying to develop a Tree Like structure with the catch being, node can have multiple parents.

**Input:**

Json with *nodes* and *links* info like,

```
 var graph = {
    "nodes": [  { "id" : 0},
                { "id" : 1},
                { "id" : 2},
                { "id" : 3},
                { "id" : 4},
                { "id" : 5}
            ],
    "links": [  { "target": 5, "source":  1 },
                { "target":  2, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 3, "source":  4 },
                { "target": 1, "source":  2},
                { "target":  1, "source":  0 },
                
            ]
    };
```

Note: This is just for reference as how I have the data, it may be thousands of nodes.

**Output:**

I want the output like a tree structure, somewhat like [this](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html), as in to say the nodes must be plotted in a depth/level like structure with root being on the top and same level nodes arranged in such a way to minimize the link overlap.

**Edit:** The output for the input provided above is [image: this] Assuming Zero is root.

**Problems I am facing:**

1. As I am only given nodes and their source & target, not their coordinates, I have to parse through the whole list calculate the level, then divide the height based on that level and then plot the nodes. What is the most efficient way to handle this kind of problem? Should I go deep into the algorithmic solution?

Or

2. Is there some graph plotting function in D3 which takes this JSON as input and does the the rest of the job?

Please not that the nodes can have multiple parent and my main focus here is plotting of these nodes in a proper/hierarchical order, so the main problem I am facing is calculating the X/Y coordinates for all the nodes given just the input as stated above.

Please help me understand this topic better and Thank you.

Comment: I can't figure out your expected output.  **Assuming zero** is the root node, would it [look like this](http://imgur.com/a/FZCrP).  3 to 4 goes away as it fails the parent/child relationship...  Is this your expected output?

Comment: @Mark Actually the input is just for reference as how the input I have...it may contain thousands of nodes, the excepted output regardless is that which ever is the root node should appear on the top, then its childs and so on with minimum link overlap. Hope I was able to explain myself ;)

Comment: But is my diagram the expected output given your sample data?

Comment: @Mark Not completely, level 1 should contain 0 as root, then its lower level 2 should have 2 and 1, just as you have but the last level 3 should only have 5 connected with 1, there should not be another 1 on level 3...thanks for pointing it out I will update the question with a proper output for the given input.

Comment: I suggest drawing a picture.  I'm even more confused after reading your last comment, then I was originally :)

Comment: @Mark Plz check the updated question. Image added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been thinking about this off and on all day.  With built-in `d3` constructs, I think [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500) is about as close as you are going to get.  I've taken your data and converted it to a version 4 example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #aaa;
    stroke-width: 5px;
  }
  
  .nodes circle {
    pointer-events: all;
    stroke: none;
  }
</style>
<svg width="600" height="300"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("y", d3.forceY())

  var graph = {
    "nodes": [{
      "id": 0
    }, {
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "id": 2
    }, {
      "id": 3
    }, {
      "id": 4
    }, {
      "id": 5
    }],
    "links": [{
        "target": 5,
        "source": 1
      }, {
        "target": 2,
        "source": 0
      }, {
        "target": 3,
        "source": 4
      }, {
        "target": 1,
        "source": 2
      }, {
        "target": 1,
        "source": 0
      },

    ]
  };

  var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line");

  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10);

  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {

    var k = 6 * simulation.alpha();

    // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
    link
      .each(function(d) {
        d.source.y -= k, d.target.y += k;
      })
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });

  }
</script>
```

If you don't want the movement and settle effect, you can pre-compute the layout to make it [static](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139).

---

I also experimented with converting your data to a hierarchical format for use with [d3.tree](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#tree) but didn't have much luck replicating your image:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .node circle {
    fill: #999;
  }
  
  .node text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .node--internal circle {
    fill: #555;
  }
  
  .node--internal text {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  }
  
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var graph = {
    "nodes": [{
      "id": 0
    }, {
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "id": 2
    }, {
      "id": 3
    }, {
      "id": 4
    }, {
      "id": 5
    }],
    "links": [{
      "target": 5,
      "source": 1
    },{
      "target": 2,
      "source": 0
    }, {
      "target": 3,
      "source": 4
    }, {
      "target": 1,
      "source": 2
    }, {
      "target": 1,
      "source": 0
    }]
  };

  var root = {
    id: 0,
    data: graph.nodes[0],
    children: []
  }

  function recurChild(obj) {
    graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.source === obj.id) {
        var c = {
          id: d.target,
          data: graph.nodes[d.target],
          children: []
        };
        obj.children.push(c);
        recurChild(c);
      }
    });
  }
  recurChild(root);

  root = d3.hierarchy(root);

  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

  var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([height, width - 160]);

  tree(root);
  
  console.log(root.descendants())

  var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
    });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    })

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 3)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children ? -8 : 8;
    })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.id;
    });
</script>
```

d3.hierarchy really implies just that, straight hierarchy with no multiple parent structure.

Comment: Cool! It seems to work for a small no of nodes, let me try it for larger number, will post back the results.

Comment: I followed your link to Force Directed Tree it was more to the answer I was looking, but the problem is with large no of nodes its kinda becomes a cluster....is there a way to provide a depth attribute to each node, like level one?

Comment: @Mohit, do you have any example coded up?  I tried to recreate with random data but without a proper parent/child structure it was a mess.  In the above code `var k = 6 * simulation.alpha();`, the `6` is the forced distance for each node.

Comment: Lets say I an using this data https://api.myjson.com/bins/rewu for plotting of graph...the main problem is the depth of root and hence the child nodes, it varies on refresh. Now if I wanted the root to on top always and its the depth in a vertical way, then? Am I able to make myself understandable? ;)